# Why is one side of the armature affecting every bone?

Tags: modifiers, armature, pose-mode

I am using the skin modifier for the first time and have seem to run into an issue... When making the armature, the right side bones when rotated affected every bone. The left side however is perfectly fine and works how it should... Does anyone know what the problem is?

[image: In the image I am rotating the right arm bone, and it seems to rotate every bone]

Comment: If you can share the blend file to see the problem, maybe I can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve the problem select the bones that were affecting the entire mesh in *Edit Mode*, go under *Armature*, and click *Switch Direction*. Now everything works.